# Suspend all processes from a specified folder

Tags: batch-file, process, windows-7, suspend

What I'm trying to do is suspend multiple processes from a single folder in Windows 7. I can get a list of such proccessses using the following commands:

```
WMIC PROCESS WHERE 'ExecutablePath like "c:\\users%"' GET
```

or

```
WMIC PROCESS WHERE 'ExecutablePath like "c:\\users%"' LIST
```

Then I need to suspend the proccesses that are returned by those commands. I can do that by using [PsSuspend](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/pssuspend.aspx) software. So, the only thing I have troubles with is looping through the list and executing this command for each process. It's rather easy to do in bash scripts, but how do I do it easily in Windows? I would prefer to use a `.bat` file or something similar, so it won't get overly complicated.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example:

```bat
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions

Rem Command
(Set WC=Process)
Rem Filter
(Set WF=ExecutablePath Like)
Rem Value
(Set FV=%UserProfile%)
Rem Output
(Set RO=ProcessID)
Rem Run
(Set RC=PsSuspend)

For /F "UseBackQ Skip=1" %%A In (
    `WMIC %WC% Where "%WF% '%FV:\=\\%%%'" Get %RO%`) Do For %%B In (%%A
    ) Do %RC% %%B
```

I changed line 9 to **%UserProfile%** you can change it back to **C:\Users** if you think I've assumed wrongly.